# Deserialize objects - class changed

Tags: java, android, serialization

I serialized an array of objects in the past without a serialUID, but in the meantime I have changed the class- I added a boolean.
Now I can't restore the objects.
I've tried to recreate the old class (from svn) and removed the warning about "no serial uid" so as to get the serialUID generated from Eclipse. I tried pasting this into my new version of the class, but it still fails. I'm not sure if this is because removing the warning changes the generated serialUID.
Next I tried to use the tool "serialver", but I keep getting a "class not found" error.

Could someone spell out for me what I should type in the commandline, as I'm not entirely sure what to type in the classpath?
I used this as my template:
serialver -classpath C:\foo\classes.jar com.bar.FooMessage
My workspace is D:\blabla\androidworkspace
Project is Shows so in eclipse it says:
Shows-src-xyz-show.java
and I run the command from C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin

Answer (score 0):

Here is good explanation how serialization works http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/2915

what you need to do is:

get serialized bytes and analyze them, 
those bytes contains your original class serial number,

then you should set serial number to you code and compile
like static final long serialVersionUID = ;

Comment: Not feasible. Where in the stream is the serial number again? Serialver and the exception message itself are all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Run the `serialver` utility on the original .class file. That will tell you its computed serialVersionUID. Then edit the new source to declare that.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do, but somehow fail. I'm unsure what exactly to write. The class is Show.java and my workspace is D:\blabla\androidworkspace Project is called Shows, so in eclipse it is displayed as: Shows-> src-> xyz-> Show.java

Comment: @Crunch You only have to write `private static final long serialVersionUID = ???L;`, as shown by *running* the `serialver` utility. I have no idea what your workspace or Eclipse have to do with it.

Comment: I know what to write in the class. My problem is how to write the command for the SerialVer tool.

Comment: @Crunch The tool is documented. It would be futile for me to repeat it here.

Answer (score 0):

I found one example here http://rchandratech.blogspot.com/2015/05/using-serialver-jdk-command.html,

Try in Eclipse, from command line go till project/bin where the class file is located, then serialver -classpath "./" com.xxx.xxx.